# Change message - "Sorry this site is not shared with you"

Tags: sharepoint-server, branding

Is it possible to change this message

> Sorry this site is not shared with you

to something else when users don't have permissions?

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about the `AccessDenied.aspx` page, then no. The text on the page is retrieved from resource files.

Unless you physically alter the page in the 15 hive on your web front-ends - which is possible, but not recommended and they can be overwritten by CU's etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended not to modify the OOB things or content. I would say to go with your custom access denied page. To do this, in SP2013 we have a bug and can achieve using HTTPModule. Please look into the following URL for more details.

[Custom Access Denied Page](http://a2zdinesh.blogspot.in/2014/05/configure-custom-access-denied-page-bug.html)

[Steps to create HTTP Module](http://a2zdinesh.blogspot.in/2014/06/create-httpmodule-step-wise-explained.html)

Please let me know if you have any queries.