# Modify text of access denied

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, access-denied

I am trying to modify the text of the message "Sorry, you Don't have access to this page" in the Access Denied page, All solutions found on the net didn't respond to my problem, I am searching the ressouces file that contains this text and modify it directly..
I am using SharePoint2013..
Thanks for help.

Comment: Check this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149366/change-message-sorry-this-site-is-not-shared-with-you

Answer (score 0):

You can go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\, find the AccessDenied.aspx page then customize it based on your requirement.

Note: Before you change the files, remember to make a backup for this file.

two similar threads for your reference:
[SharePoint 2013: how to create a custom access denied page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31253.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-access-denied-page.aspx)
[Custom access denied page SharePoint 2013](https://fullvoga.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/custom-access-denied-page/)